# Blazor Serverside singleton service, Changes in one browser are reflected in another, when loading the same page

Tags: blazor-server-side

In Blazor serverside, I created a shopping cart in a website using a singleton service, And I expected different users have different instances of this service, But when I load the website in two types of browsers, Adding an Item to cart is reflected in another browser, And even I can see the change, (I also used a singleton service for each user's data and the site is published to the web). Is this the correct behaviour for singleton services and how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected behavior of a singleton service. In your case you should use the scoped service.

**Transient** lifetime services (AddTransient) are created each time they're requested from the service container. This lifetime works best for lightweight, stateless services.

**Scoped** lifetime services (AddScoped) are created once per client request (connection).

**Singleton** lifetime services (AddSingleton) are created the first time they're requested (or when Startup.ConfigureServices is run and an instance is specified with the service registration). Every subsequent request uses the same instance. If the app requires singleton behavior, allowing the service container to manage the service's lifetime is recommended. Don't implement the singleton design pattern and provide user code to manage the object's lifetime in the class.

Taken from the [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1#service-lifetimes).

Also, note that lifetimes work differently in Blazor WebAssembly and Blazor Server. See [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-6.0).